# Не печатает все страницы в один файл pdf

Tags: excel, pdf

Выделяю 7 страниц в эксель файле и печатаю в pdf (принтер doPdf).
Раньше все печаталось нормально и вот в один прекрасный день, на каждый лист стал требовать указать путь в отдельный файл.
Настройки печати не менял. Куда смотреть?

Comment: Excel - Print - Collate pages?

Comment: Разобрать по копиям по русски? Да. Попробовал отжал эту галку, ничего не поменялось...